# Tesseract to omit numbers

Tags: image-processing, command-line, ocr, tesseract

Good day all,

I am using Tesseract off the command prompt to read an image file containing a name. The output contains numbers which I want to omit. I attempted to include a config file containing the following:

```
tessedit_char_whitelist abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

After which I run the command `Tesseract image.jpg out nobatch configs`

The output only includes letters now, but the result is way off as compared to the first result. Anyone with experience on Tesseract able to advise?
Thanks in advance!

Regards

Comment: what kind of image do you use? try converting the source image to tiff using imagemagick

Comment: its a jpg. Yes, even if it is tiff and 300 DPI. Issue is that it is able to return better results without the whitelist configured.

Comment: could you put the path of your configs file ?

Comment: Is there a reason why you do not use _regex_ programs after retrieving  the output from Tesseract?

Comment: hi all. thank you for the responses. path of config file is in same directory as tesseract exe. Seems like a reasonable approach to remove numbers after extracting the result, but i am just exploring ways to omit from tesseract to be more efficient.

Comment: Hi all, manage to removed the numbers and not affecting the output. As pointed out by dervish, I changed the directory of the config file and it works. Thank you all!